# Failed to execute PMD as java file is being ignored

Tags: java, postgresql, assembly, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube 4.5.1 , project is written with java 8 code and pmd-5.2.1. Also postgresql is database used by sonar.
Sonarqube is compatible with java 8 projects.

I have a sonar job which is success in jenkins, but during analysis i find the below error.

I can see the dashboard but i am not sure if the values are correct or not.

Fail to execute PMD. Following file is ignored: /home/jenkins/workspace/project/src/main/java/com/filemethod.java

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INVOKESPECIAL/STATIC on interfaces require ASM 5
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.getImportedClasses(PMDASMClassLoader.java:77) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.populateClassName(ClassTypeResolver.java:728) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:153) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:42) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.TypeResolutionFacade.initializeWith(TypeResolutionFacade.java:17) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$5.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:88) ~[pmd-java-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.usesTypeResolution(SourceCodeProcessor.java:127) ~[pmd-core-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:142) ~[pmd-core-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:76) ~[pmd-core-5.2.1.jar:na]
at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:43) ~[pmd-core-5.2.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdTemplate.process(PmdTemplate.java:83) ~[sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:119) [sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:89) [sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:75) [sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:67) [sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar:na]
```

When i googled it i found https://github.com/Sable/soot/issues/225

Similar issue was raised last year. but is it solved now?
is java 8 compatible with asm 5?

what can be done here?

Thank you